# PHPMailer SMTP connection error

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I've been trying to figure out how to get `phpMailer` to work for the last few hours. I keep getting errors. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

require("class.phpmailer.php");
$mail = new PHPMailer(); 
$mail->IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // turn on SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "******@gmail.com"; // SMTP username
$mail->Password = "******"; // SMTP password
$host = "smtp.mandrillapp.com";
$port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';  
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;
$webmaster_email = "****@gmail.com"; //Reply to this email ID
$email= $email; // Recipients email ID
$name= $name; // Recipient's name
$mail->From = $webmaster_email;
$mail->FromName = "University of Life Experiences";
$mail->AddAddress($email,$name);
$mail->AddReplyTo($webmaster_email,"Webmaster");
$mail->WordWrap = 50; // set word wrap
$mail->IsHTML(true); // send as HTML
$mail->Subject = "ULE";
$mail->Body = $message; //HTML Body
$mail->AltBody = $message; //Text Body
if(!$mail->Send())
{
echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
else
{
echo "Message has been sent";
}
?>
```

Here is the error I have been receiving:

> SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0) SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.

I have tried many different SMTP servers including Gmail and I always get a similar error about failing to connect.

Please help, I have tried many other `phpMailer` example codes all with the same issue. If anyone can recommend any other PHP mailing programs that would be useful. The reason I am not using the inbuilt `mail()` function.

Comment: Are you tring to use those smtp from localhost?

Comment: That's *all* the information you get even with `SMTPDebug = 1`?

Comment: Are you using a hosted webserver? Maybe a firewall is blocking port 25. If you can connect via ssh, try `telnet yourserver smtp` and see what happens.

Comment: You need to assign `host` ($host) & `port` ($port) to phpmailer object.

Comment: Did you try with changing SMTPsecure from ssl to tls.
`$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';`

Comment: Tried all answers, still getting same error. Also this is all the info debug is providing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't set the SMTP Host ( though you declare the variable `$host` ). Set it via:

```
$mail->host = $host;
```

Thanks @Rikesh for reminding, `$port` is also the same case.

Side Note: I noticed you use gmail.com as reply email but your SMTP server is not gmail. This may cause some email servers to put your email to spam / junk folder.

Comment: Hey man, thanks for the answer but I tried this and it didnt work, same error. Tried from WAMP and webserver

Comment: Did you try to telnet to the SMTP server ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this by adding :

```
$mail->Mailer   = "SMTP"; // SMTP Method
```

Refer this link [PHP Mailer help](http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/423836/smtp-error-could-not-connect-to-smtp-host)

Comment: @Mukil OP has already stated `$mail->IsSMTP(); // send via SMTP`. Also, the link you provided is NOT official documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the port number

```
$port = 587;
```

to

```
$port = 465;
```

and check what new error you are getting , i am sure you will not get SMTP connect error again.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use SSL:

```php
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
$mail->Port = 465;                        // ssl
```

2. Add this in your php file:

```php
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
'ssl' => array(
    'verify_peer' => false,
    'verify_peer_name' => false,
    'allow_self_signed' => true
    )
);
```

3. In `myaccount.gmail.com` > `Sign-in & security` > `Apps with account access` set `Allow less secure apps` to  `ON`.